# React Native firebase realtimedatabase query inside useEffect() looping

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

Hey guys I am trying to get data from firebase's real-time database with problems. I am unable to find a way to wait for the useEffect() to finish the firebase query before returning the line chart to the react-native application, I am using expo to build the project onto an android emulated device running android 11.  [This is the error here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhzpp.png) I am able to get it working by posting static data to the graph then changing the data after the firebase query is done. [before edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofre8.png) & [after edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sem5g.png) any help would be appreciated or a link which yet I have not been able to find. :)

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import { LineChart } from "react-native-chart-kit";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  Temputure: {
    fontSize: 10,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  separator: {
    marginVertical: 30,
    height: 1,
    width: "80%",
  },
});

export default function FireBaseTest() {
  const [Temputure, setTemputure] = useState([]);
  const [date, setDate] = useState();
  const [time, setTime] = useState([]);
  const graphTimeLengh = 12;

  useEffect(() => {
    const db = firebase.database();
    const temparray = [];
    for (let i = -1; i < graphTimeLengh; i++) {
      db.ref("0/20-08-2021 " + i + "/0/Temp").on("value", (snapshot) => {
        const response = snapshot.val();
        temparray[i] = response;
      });
    }
    setTemputure(temparray);
    db.ref("0/20-08-2021 0/0/Date").on("value", (snapshot) => {
      const response = snapshot.val();
      setDate(response);
    });

    const timearray = [];
    for (let i = -1; i < graphTimeLengh; i++) {
      db.ref("0/20-08-2021 " + i + "/0/Time").on("value", (snapshot) => {
        const response = snapshot.val();
        timearray[i] = response;
      });
    }
    setTime(timearray);
  }, [date, time, Temputure]);

  const linedata = {
    labels: time,
    datasets: [
      {
        data: Temputure,
        strokeWidth: 5, // optional
      },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>FireBaseTest</Text>

      <Text>{date}</Text>

      <LineChart
        data={linedata}
        width={Dimensions.get("window").width}
        height={220}
        yAxisSuffix="°C"
        yAxisInterval={1}
        fromZero={true}
        chartConfig={{
          backgroundColor: "#1cc910",
          backgroundGradientFrom: "#eff3ff",
          backgroundGradientTo: "#efefef",
          decimalPlaces: 1,
          color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 0, 0, ${opacity})`,
          style: {
            borderRadius: 16,
          },
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Sorry if this question is worded badly it's my first one and trying to follow the question format. Also any advice for next time i want to post a question and what to add would be appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just changed my line data into a state that will be updated after the useeffect has got to it but presents "wait" and 1 while waiting

```
import firebase from "./firebase";
import * as React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import { LineChart } from "react-native-chart-kit";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  Temputure: {
    fontSize: 10,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  separator: {
    marginVertical: 30,
    height: 1,
    width: "80%",
  },
});

export default function FireBaseTest() {
  const [Temputure, setTemputure] = useState([1]);
  const [date, setDate] = useState();
  const [time, setTime] = useState(["Wait"]);
  const graphTimeLengh = 12;
  const db = firebase.database();

  const linedata = {
    labels: time,
    datasets: [
      {
        data: Temputure,
        strokeWidth: 5,
      },
    ],
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const temparray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < graphTimeLengh; i++) {
      db.ref("0/20-08-2021 " + i + "/0/Temp").on("value", (snapshot) => {
        const response = snapshot.val();
        temparray[i] = response;
      });
    }
    db.ref("0/20-08-2021 0/0/Date").on("value", (snapshot) => {
      const response = snapshot.val();
      setDate(response);
    });
    const timearray = [];
    for (let i = -1; i < graphTimeLengh; i++) {
      db.ref("0/20-08-2021 " + i + "/0/Time").on("value", (snapshot) => {
        const response = snapshot.val();
        timearray[i] = response;
      });
    }

    setTemputure(temparray);
    setTime(timearray);
  }, [db]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>FireBaseTest</Text>

      <Text>{date}</Text>

      <LineChart
        data={linedata}
        width={Dimensions.get("window").width}
        height={220}
        yAxisSuffix="°C"
        yAxisInterval={1}
        fromZero={true}
        chartConfig={{
          backgroundColor: "#1cc910",
          backgroundGradientFrom: "#eff3ff",
          backgroundGradientTo: "#efefef",
          decimalPlaces: 1,
          color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 0, 0, ${opacity})`,
          style: {
            borderRadius: 16,
          },
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```